# Importing from .dll file objects WithEvents to C++ command line application

Tags: c++, vb.net, visual-studio, dll, mfc

I'm building a C++ command line application in which I need to import and use a dll file , for which I have only examples in VB, that has a main objects which also has Events that I need to access.

I have managed to include it by adding the MFC headers, but now I'm struggling to make their events work.

Importing the dll resulted in me having a CAdministrator.h , which include all but the events, and CIAdministratorEvents.h, which includes the Events.
While I have successfully created a CAdministrator, I have no idea how to access his events.

Code from the CIAdministratorEvents.h, showing an Event I need to access:

```
#import "C:\\My.dll" no_namespace
// CIAdministratorEvents wrapper class

class CIAdministratorEvents : public COleDispatchDriver
{
public:
    CIAdministratorEvents(){} // Calls COleDispatchDriver default constructor
    CIAdministratorEvents(LPDISPATCH pDispatch) : COleDispatchDriver(pDispatch) {}
    CIAdministratorEvents(const CIAdministratorEvents& dispatchSrc) : COleDispatchDriver(dispatchSrc) {}


// _IAdministratorEvents methods
public:

STDMETHOD(NewError)(LPCTSTR bsError, long hError)
{
    HRESULT result;
    static BYTE parms[] = VTS_BSTR VTS_I4 ;
    InvokeHelper(0x4, DISPATCH_METHOD, VT_HRESULT, (void*)&result, parms, bsError, hError);
    return result;
}
```

Comment: What is your specific question? Do you want to access CAdministrator's events? You have to give us some thing hard to work on. We can't fix your errors if we don't know what your errors are.

Comment: Yes, I need to access the CAdministrator events, that exist in another header file. I have added a part of the CIAdminEvents.h that show one Event function I need to access. The CAdmin.h is quite simple and as I said, I can access it with a simple `CAdministrator some_admin;`. Please let me know what else I should provide. Thank you.

Comment: Please read about event sinks and their implementation in mfc/atl projects. It is quite simple and can be implemented with Class Wizard

Comment: Can you share a link? I've never heard of event sinks before...

Comment: Read [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9014/Understanding-COM-Event-Handling), [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2kxtf8s3.aspx), and [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/baytax3s.aspx)

Comment: After quite some reading, I'm stuck a bit. I'm not sure what my `ISomeInterface` should be. Is it derived from my CAdmin class or from my CIAdminEvents? I found that I can call on objects of both the var m_lpDispatch that seems to be accepted as an interface... Also you said it should be accessible through the class wizard. Is there way to link the two classes?